# How not to wait a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I have FuncA who call FuncB .I want FuncA to continue processing without waiting FuncB to be finished.
Is this possible in JavaScript?

Comment: Is FuncB  async?

Comment: If you tag your question with `async-await` and `asynchronous`, then surely you know it's possible.

Comment: If this question is about JavaScript, why is it tagged [tag:processing]? Please **take care when selecting tags**.

Comment: I did ... but FuncA is waiting the end of FuncBfunction FuncB() {
    console.log("FuncB started");
    for (var t = 0; t < 100; t++) {
        console.log("value of t funcB" + t);
    }
}

 function FuncA() {
    console.log('calling');
     FuncB();
     console.log("FuncA loading ...")
    for (var t = 0; t < 100; t++) {
        console.log("value of t" + t);
    }
  
}

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    console.log("started");
    processA();

});

function delay() {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0));
}
async function delayedLog(j) {
    await delay();
    document.getElementById("dv1").innerHTML += "<br/>" + j;

}

async function delayedLog2(j) {
    await delay();
    document.getElementById("dv2").innerHTML += "<br/>" + j;

}


async function processA() {

    processB();

    for (var k = 0; k < 100000; k++) {
    
        await delayedLog(k);
    }

    console.log('Done!');

}


async function processB() {


    for (var j = 0; j < 100000; j++) {

        await delayedLog2(j); 
    }

    console.log('DoneB!');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple ways of doing that, basically launching an asynchronous task, for example in the code:

```
function FuncB() {
  console.log("FuncB started");
  for (var t = 0; t < 100; t++) {
    console.log("value of t funcB" + t);
  }
}
  
function FuncA() {
  console.log('calling');
  FuncB();
  console.log("FuncA loading ...")
  for (var t = 0; t < 100; t++) {
    console.log("value of t" + t);
  }
}
```

...launch the `FuncB()` inside `FuncA()` with one on these:

```
setImmediate(() => FuncB());
setTimeout(() => FuncB());
Promise.resolve().then(() => FuncB());
```

..or if you are in NodeJS you can use too:

```
process.nextTick(() => FuncB());
```